# GPOs and files from a network share

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, group-policy

I want to use some files in my GPOs (on Windows 10), mostly some scripts or other files which I simply want to copy. The problem is that they are on a network share and the GPOs are in the Computer Configuration without the security context of a user.
I have added "domain\computer" and "Domain Computers" to the share, but the files are not copied and the EventViewer says "Access Denied".

I am new to the whole GPO/domain stuff, so maybe I am just overthinking... but it seems to me, I am missing some basic idea.

Comment: Set the share up and it's folder security for the AD group [Domain Computers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/active-directory-security-groups#bkmk-domaincomputers) and you'll be all set. Same with `Authenticated Users` too I suppose. Just be sure one of those groups have access to the share and to the folder of the share.

Comment: Still not working. Is there any way to verify that the computer has access to the file?
Or could it be a local problem? It just says "Access denied"

Comment: Where are you seeing Access Denied at exactly. Are these running as "startup scripts" or "logon scripts"? The computer will need access for Startup Scripts but I think it's time to disclose more information here. What logic is the script running, how do you have it defined to run from which specific policy within Computer Configuration, and what's the full path used for the path to these scripts? Also, Event Viewer Group Policy logs can sometimes help too.

Comment: I am not yet even trying to run the scripts, simply trying to copy them to a local path. Since the files are not copied, I had a look in the EventViewer and there it simply states  something like "Could not be copied, Access denied" (roughly translated, because the error messages are in German). There is no information about whether it is the local path or the network share it cannot access. Sorry, the initial question was unclear on that, I tried to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this helps anyone, but in this case, the problem was the system set-up (I have no influence on that). Although, computers are part of domain computers group, access is denied to this group to all shares on some level. I had to add the computers to a special organisation related group (XXXGM-Clients) and grant access to the share to that group.